# STM32F429 PWM GLITCH

Tags: pwm, stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubemx

I have set up Timer 1 Channel 1 for pwm mode 1. I used the STM32CUBE to generate code for MDK-ARM. Parameters as below-

```
CLOCK: 160 Mhz
CLK_DIV:NONE
PRESCALE: 3
PERIOD:3999
```

Period value for channel 1 is 1999 for 50% duty cycle.

I have verified the parameters by looking at the registers in a debug session.

This is giving me output at 10 kHz as expected (confirmed on scope). However... there is a glitch. Every 200 milliseconds or so, the output goes to a low level for a short period( couple of milliseconds). If I change output frequency to 20kHz, the interruption gets shortened to 100 mS, exactly half. I am not updating the timer parameters at all (so preload does not matter). Changing the channel replicates the issue on the other channel. No other code is running. No interrupts. Why is this happening? I would very much appreciate some help. I will be able to post some code tomorrow, but since it is CUBE generated, I assume it is correct.

Rough outline:

1. Setup GPIO
2. Setup Timer 1
3. Start pwm on channel 1
4. Infinite loop.

Comment: You should consider posting your code.  In your debugger, can you catch the delay?  What is the ARM doing during the glitch?

Comment: I will be able to post the actual code tomorrow once I get back to work. This issue has been frustrating me for a while now. The only way I can describe it is like this- the single waveform period at 10 kHz is 0.0001 seconds. If you take 2000 of these, you get 200 mS. Exactly the time when I get the glitch. As if I have reversed the period for timer 1 with compare for pwm channel 1. Which is clearly not the case since I have verified the registers and I wouldn't get the proper waveform after zooming in on the scope.I am not sure how to catch the delay on the debugger.

Comment: The calculation seems to be simple and correct. 160 Mhz div by Prescale (3+1) is 40 Mhz. Divide by period (3999+1) gives 10 kHz carrier, and (1999+1) gives 50% duty cycle. Does that sound right?